# Adding Relax and Recover to an Automated Backup Workflow (REAR)

Tags: linux, centos

I have 3 drives on my system, which is a web application with a database:

1. CentOS 8 (1TB NVMe SSD)
2. Automated Database Backup Storage (1TB SSD)
3. REAR Backup Storage - Currently Planning (1TB SSD)

My system will use up to 700GB on Drive 1. Additionally, my database is backed up to a gzip'd CSV every three days at 4AM to Drive 2. I store the last 10 backups - this is primarily to move data to another machine but also serves as a backup system.

I want to add additional redundancy. I plan to dedicate Drive 3 to Relax And Recover 2.6 (REAR). I will use Cron to automate backups every night at midnight.

My Cron would look like this:

```
0 0 * * * root /usr/sbin/rear mkbackup
```

Which I have confirmed `mkbackup` creates a rescue system and backs up the user files.

Since the REAR backup would run every night at midnight, the space on Drive 3 would quickly fill up. Does REAR know to overwrite the last backup if the local backup drive does not have enough space to create a new one?

If it does not know how to overwrite the last backup, how could I handle this? My thought would be to create a script that formats Drive 3, then makes a backup (i.e., `rear format /mnt/backups`) and call that script from Cron.